# MySql query price between range

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Okay so I made this query for my search page:

```
SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `ad_price` >= 0 AND `ad_price` <= 300
```

This part shows different results based on adding these guys: ""

```
>= 0 AND `ad_price` <= 300
```

if i say `` >= 0 AND `ad_price` <= 300 ``

The data returns anything between 0 and 30 but if i say `` >= "0" AND `ad_price` <= "300" `` it gets numbers up to 10,000 and 2000 etc.. why?

Here is my fully PHP prepared statement(i know they get treated as strings but how do I change that if it's in a prepared statement):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `ad_title` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_brand` 
LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%') AND `ad_price` >= ? AND `ad_price` <= ?"; 
$get_posts = $conn_posts->prepare($query);
$get_posts->bind_param("ssss", $title, $brand, $min_range, $max_range);
```

Comment: If you put the numbers in quote marks they'll be treated as strings instead of numbers. String comparisons work differently to numeric comparisons. Obviously we can't see the table schema or sample data, but that's what I'd expect. P.S. This seems to have nothing to do with PHP?

Comment: @ADyson as i need it to work for my search

Comment: @ADyson sorry i will remove the php tag your right i accidentally added it.

Comment: Except now you've shown us some PHP code... please edit that into your question (not the comments) if it's relevant

Comment: @ADyson okay i will add it in my post

Comment: "ssss" tells mysql to treat all the values as strings. Use `i` for the parameters you want to be treated as numbers. Check the manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"ssss"` tells mysql to treat all the input values as strings. Use `i` for the parameters you want to be treated as numbers.

e.g.

```
"ssii"
```

in your case.

This is documented in the manual: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: This doesn't explain why `ad_price` is treated as a string. My guess is that it's actually a VARCHAR